# Syntax explanation: () -> Text in Swift

Tags: swift, swiftui, return-value

I just came across a syntax which I don't understand.
I have the following constant in my struct

```
  let text: ()-> Text
```

Can somebody explain to me what does it represent and how can I use it when I initiate the struct?[image]

Comment: This is a closure returning Text. https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/Closures.html

Comment: Thank you. So it means I have to create a function that will have an input String and output Text. And call this function above where I initiate the struct, right?

Comment: No input, `() means no arguments`, just return `Text`... Learn referenced document.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This is a constant, which is of type closure that accepts no parameter and has an output of type Text.

Answer (score -1):

() A closure that accepts no parameters and -> has the the return value text